dynamicDarkColorScheme always reports the same primary color no matter the wallpaper
I'm seeing some behavior I don't understand on my Galaxy S23 running Android 14. In my JetPack Compose app, dynamicDarkColorTheme always reports the same color no matter the selection of wallpaper or color palette. I'm using the phone's Wallpaper and Style settings to change wallpapers and palettes. Below is some debug output I captured while changing wallpapers and palettes.
  D  dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=Color(0.6784314, 0.7764706, 1.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
  D  dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=Color(0.6784314, 0.7764706, 1.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
  D  dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=Color(0.6784314, 0.7764706, 1.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
  D  dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=Color(0.6784314, 0.7764706, 1.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
  D  dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=Color(0.6784314, 0.7764706, 1.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)

and the code in my ColorTheme function to print this is:
val color = dynamicDarkColorScheme(context).primary.toString()
Log.d("palettecolor","dynamicDarkColorScheme.primary=$color")

If I run the app in the simulator (Pixel 6) dynamicDarkColorScheme works as expected returning different colors.
Is there something extra I need to do for this to work on Galaxy S23 phones?
